# Python requests remove Connection header

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently needing to make a single HTTP request to a bunch of servers that I have in a list however, these HTTP requests contain a 'Connection' header, which I need to remove.  How would I do this?

I had the same issue with Accept-Encoding, but I was able to comment out the section that automatically applies that header in httpclient.py (I'm using the requests lib for this).  Is there any way around this aside from using sockets and sending raw HTTP requests?  Is there maybe another snippet that can be commented out to prevent the header from being automatically added?

I realize that removing the header is a bad idea in the real world, but there's justification for this and it 100% needs to be removed.

I've tried assign it as empty and NoneType, both appear to be failing.  I'm wondering if this is something I can't change.

Comment: You need some code to go with that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can actually patch this out by commenting out line 1180 in urllib2.py

```
headers["Connection"] = "close"
```